# Debugging Python script using Visual Studio in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, visual-studio

According to these links, one can debug a Python script using Visual Studio in ArcGIS Pro.
[Debug Python code—ArcPy Get Started | ArcGIS Desktop](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/debugging-python-code.htm)

[ArcGIS Pro and Python - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrp46oVBiEY)

I am using ArcGIS pro version 2.3 and Visual studio 2017.
My steps

1. Downloaded the 'Python development' workload to visual studio Pro 2017.
2. Edited my .py file to add some intentional errors for testing.
3. Opened ArcGIS Pro with my tool and my data to be run.
4. Opened my .py file in Visual Studio and added some breakpoints.
5. Attached to process
   in Visual Studio. See image below:

[image]

6. Ran my script tool in ArcGIS Pro.

The tool fails in ArcGIS Pro because it has errors but I am not re routed to Visual Studio to see the error line as I expected. I then removed the errors in the code and left only the breakpoints but I still wasn't able to hit the breakpoints. Again, the tool completed without re-routing me back to visual studio. Has anyone been able to successfully debug Python tools using Visual Studio Pro 2017 in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: I've never gotten "debug arcpy in XYZ" to work in anything other the standard python interpreter and ipython

Comment: The top link suggests not to connect to ArcGISPro but connect to a Python instance.

Comment: @klewis The link does say to attach visual studio to ArcGIS Pro. It says to attach to 'python code' in visual studio as I did in the image I posted in the original question.

Comment: @PaulH, Esri has demo videos where they get it to work so I figured it's possible.

Comment: I have VS 2017 and I can debug from ArcPro. Open your script in VS, set a breakpoint, attach to Pro, run the script tool from Pro, it should stop at the breakpoint. I have to reattach to ArcPro every time for some reason.

Comment: @ketar I'm well aware. I'm just saying that I've never found their explanations sufficient to get it going on my machines. However, python's and ipython's debuggers have never let me down.

Comment: @klewis,I followed your workflow but for some reason my breakpoints are never hit. Even when I induce errors, I am not taken back to visual studio.

Comment: @PaulH Are you able to attach Ipython to ArcGIS PRO such that a script run from ArcGIS Pro can be debugged in IPython?

Comment: @ketar no I just run the script from ipython (or a jupyter notebook most likely)

Comment: @ketar, the esri help doc says you must have Pro version 2.1 or later for VS debugging to work. Also, I have Anaconda 5.0.0 selected in the bottom dialog for  my Python env.

Comment: @klewis, I have edited the question to say that I am using ArcGIS pro version 2.3. I haven't used python environments. Would it matter for debugging to work? Are you talking about the python environment in ArcGIS Pro's backstage, under 'manage environments'?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with VS 2019 and ArcGIS Pro 2.8.
For me it was because 'Python Code' and '(.NET 4x)' were selected at the attach process. When I just selected the 'Python' it worked.

Comment: Mine has always just been python code. No .net. I have found that on first attaching, it doesn't work but when I detach and re attach after the first attempt, I am able to hit the breakpoints. It's a trial and error process.